# How to get all ip address of azure function app to whitelist them?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, ip-address, azure-function-app

I have one azure function which call clients api.

Client want a azure function ip address to whitelist them in there api network so that my azure function can access there api.

I tried to give them all `Outbound Ip Address` I can get from azure function properties but i can see everytime im getting all new ip address.

How to get all possible ip address which i can give client to whitelist pls advice.
For production im using `App Service Plan (S1: 1)`

[image]

Comment: can you whitelist the fqdn ?

Comment: will that work ? can you give me any blog post how to do that? thanks

Comment: Maybe this doc could be helpful:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses#find-outbound-ip-addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this. There are different possibilities depending on the pricing tier. From not possible at all, to possible but may change, to possible and guaranteed that IP address will not change.

The bad news is that, possible and guaranteed that IP address will not change, requires using the isolated tier.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses#dedicated-ip-addresses

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into using service tags: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/service-tags-overview#available-service-tags

/MMT